# Relation between density and refractive index of medium

Tags: solid-state-physics

Is there any relation between Refractive index and density of a material? It is not found to be proportional in my experimental results. Is there any equation to relate these parameters?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about solids and liquids as they are almost incompressible, but for gases, it should be varying with pressure and temperature. Since gas density is also a function of pressure and temperature, I expect it to be a factor (See [this article for example](http://www.kayelaby.npl.co.uk/general_physics/2_5/2_5_7.html)). I hope someone familiar can explain further.

Comment: Sure, for low enough densitites the relationship is roughly linear a fact that is sometimes used in gas Cerenkov detectors for tuning the threshold.

Answer (score 0):

I undertook an experimental project at school, using a Michelson Interferometer investigating relationship between Refractive Index and gases at varying temperatures and pressures. The relationship between refractive index and pressure was linear. The relationship between refractive index and temperature was also linear. As this was a submitted study, I no longer have the report…it was also done in 1980… so apologies for the lack of a definitive relationship between Pressure and Refractive index… which was established in the report but escapes my memory after 42 years!