# Is refractive index dependent on mass density?

Tags: refraction

The refractive index is dependent on temperature. As temperature increases the refractive index of the medium decreases. So is refractive index dependent on mass density?

Comment: Also [Correlation between the refractive index and the density](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/491491/correlation-between-the-refractive-index-and-the-density)

Answer (score 0):

It's often the case that denser materials have a higher refractive index, but it's not always true.

According to [this website](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-does-optical-density-relate-to-mass-density-and-refractive-index.706985/)  an exception is vegetable oil (n=1.47) and water (n=1.33), but oil floats on water so is less dense.